# ngfor unpacking 2 variables at a time

Tags: angular, ngfor, iterable-unpacking

In python I can do this to unpack both variables in each tuple at each iteration.

```
l = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (8, 9)]
for k,v in l:
     print("k = ", k)
     print("v = ", v)
     print("-------")

#   k =  1
#   v =  2
#   -------
#   k =  4
#   v =  5
#   -------
#   k =  8
#   v =  9
#   -------
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can do something similar in angular.

Say we have `keyValues = [[1,2], [4,5], [8,9]]`
Is there a way we can unpack each pair of numbers at each iteration? Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let k, v of keyValues">{{k}} and {{v}}</div>
```

Comment: as of current angular version, you can't destructure in templates like this. what you can do is convert your array of arrays into an array of more template friendly objects.

Comment: In python, you have a tuple array and in javascript, you have an array of arrays. There is a pipe called `keyValue` but it destructs objects, not arrays.

Comment: If you always expect an array with 2 values inside an outer array, you can *ngFor over the outer array and simply address the sub-array directly by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert that array to an object with properties (although I'm guessing you're already starting with an object?)

```js
const keyValues = [[1,2], [4,5], [8,9]]
const obj = Object.fromEntries(keyValues)
```

There's an Angular pipe that can be used to extract the key value pairs

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">
    {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```